# Compressed Array Bytes Java from .NET Webservice

Tags: java, .net, android, visual-studio-2008, eclipse

1 - From a webservice. NET 2008 (vb), I have a method that returns an array of bytes, the byte array is actually a string "Hola Mundo" ("Hello World" in English) compressed with the Class of System.IO.Compression GZipStream.

2 - The method returns the string "Hola Mundo" compressed, and this is what the webservice returns:

```
<base64Binary>
H4sIAAAAAAAEAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Ir5dlVn6xXo5q/4f0m5DIgoAAAA=
</base64Binary>
```

3 - if I do a test from a windows application from Visual Basic. NET to run this method returns me this string and Unzip with another function I have, it brings me the "Hola Mundo" ....

4 - On Android (Eclipse) and I managed to make the request and bring me the previous string ... but do not know how to decompress and show me "Hola Mundo" ...

5 - I have tried several codes from the web, but none work.

anyone know anything about this? thank you very much from now.

Greetings.

Comment: So you've compressed a 10 character string down to only 172 characters. Neat!

Comment: Hi, Marc Gravell, this is just an easy example, I actually use to compress about 3 MB of text.

Comment: it was a bit tongue-in-cheek, I'll confess ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Android supports `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream`, that's what you want.

For example:

```
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromWebService();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
try {
  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzip, "UTF-8");
  try {
    String firstLine = new BufferedReader(reader).readLine();
    ...
  } finally {
    reader.close();
  }
} finally {
  gzip.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code throws me error on line "GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bais);" java.io.IOException: Unknown format

Comment: @seba123neo: Then that suggests you haven't retrieved the byte array properly. I suggest you check the bytes in the debugger.

Comment: The line of your code "byte[] bytes = getBytesFromWebService();"
I changed to "byte [] bytes = Result.GetBytes();" where the variable "Result" contains the string "H4sIAAAAAAAEAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Ir5dlVn6xXo5q/4f0m5DIgoAAAA="

Comment: @seba123neo: Well that's not right, because it's base64-encoded. You need to base64-decode your data first.

Comment: thank you very much Jon, the problem is solved, what I did was:

1 - Decode the string with a class that I found on the Internet.
2 - the link is http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/
is very fast, and do not need to decompress with gzip, the class automatically decompresses it when it detects gzip ...
anyone know of any class faster than this?

Greetings and thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on Android, but you just need to:

- reverse the base-64
- reverse the gzip
- decode the string (presumably as UTF8)

In C#, this would be something like:

```
string base64 = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Ir5dlVn6xXo5q/4f0m5DIgoAAAA=";
byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
string orig;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(blob))
using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzip))
{
    orig = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Hola Mundo
}
```

Comment: Yeah, yeah that's exactly what I need, but in android java code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no base-64 conversion available in Android out of the package. I used the one available in the Bouncy Castle Java Cryptographic Library.
[Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Also you can find them in the ksoap2-android library.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Eli's post, ksoap2-android has byte[] org.kobjects.base64.Base64.decode(String arg0)

You can get it here: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2